# duplicate results with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When adding a list of past episodes to my site using this code:

include.php

```
class rest {
  public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM podcast");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
  }
}
```

index.php

```
$rest = new rest;
$list = $rest->fetch_all();

<h2>Past Episodes<h2>
<?php foreach ($list as $rest) { ?>
<br><br>
<?php echo $cast['cast_title']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

it displays 2 of the same (latest) title and not the 2 separate titles listed in the `cast_title` field of the database.

Am I missing something?

I sorted this by adding

```
   <?php foreach ($articles as $feedback) {
if ($feedback['cast'] === $_GET['id']) { ?>
```

Comment: What is `$cast`. I do not see where this variable is initialized.

Comment: Just a note: `SELECT *`. Do you really need everything, or just the title? `SELECT cast_title` might suffice.

Comment: thank you. changing it to rest. does the job. but how do i get it to list in reverse order?

Comment: What does it print? : `foreach ($list as $cast) { echo '<br><br>' . $cast; }`

Comment: just the title @AnotherTest

Comment: @kevstarlive then select only the title ;)

Comment: but it does the same job right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class rest 
{
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cast_title FROM podcast ORDER BY cast_title DESC");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Then template:

```
<?php
$rest = new rest;
?>

<h2>Past Episodes<h2>
<?php foreach ($rest->fetch_all() as $rest) { ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php echo $rest['cast_title']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have used `ORDER BY` clause for sorting. There is a `DESC` order, which means *descendant*, and You can use `ASC` (or none) for *ascending* order. Or You can order by different columns.